# Reading text file line by line with python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am using python 3 and pygame to read a txt file database line by line, and then blitting the image attached with that. Basically, I have a bunch of file paths linking to images in a text file, and I want to blit every image to screen. I should be right once I have an idea how to read each line individually, or just split the document at line breaks and then increasing the value in the list b 1 each time. Dont know if that made any sense whatsoever, but any help is much appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Hi Sam! Why are you talking about pygame and bitblitting while it seems like all you want to ask is "Reading text file line by line with python"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the output file in the .txt format, then try this:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
file.write(str(array)) #assuming your output is in array 
file.close()
```